# Strange behaviour in GIT diff HEAD

Tags: git, diff

I am under Windows and using GIT strictly locally, as a backup system.

I have my whole Eclipse workspace in it.

Searching on the net, I find that I need to do this:

```
Display changes since last commit:
$ git diff HEAD
```

I am trying to understand what precisely some maven plugin goal is doing. So I commit all my changes. Then I run the maven command. Then I go in the project directory, which is under the workspace directory, and run

```
git diff HEAD
```

It then shows me changes for the whole workspace, when in fact nothing has changed except in this directory. If I redirect it to a file, the file is 157M big!

But if I go one directory up, back in the workspace, and do the same, then it only shows me the change in the project directory. Which is what I would expect.

So my questions are:

1) Why, if I go in a sub-directory, it shows me changes that happened in the parent directory?

2) When there really is only that one change, where does it get the 157M of changes?

Comment: please provide an output of `git status`

Comment: If I'm in workspace, it shows the modified files as expected. If I go down in any sub-directory, it shows *every file in workspace* as modified. It's like if it always compared the current directory to the root, instead of comparing it to the same directory in the repository.

Comment: what state does the files have? Maybe some stranges settings in you git config. Also please provide git version and OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `git diff` without a path argument anywhere inside a git repository will show you the differences for the whole repository, not just the current directory (this is different than Subversion's behavior).

If you're getting different output from `git diff HEAD` in different directories, it means that you're moving to a different repository (or you're not actually running the *exact* same command).

Comment: OK, now that make sense, but if I use "." as path, it still behaves exactly like when I don't give any path. If I use a directory name then it works as expected, in the root OR in a sub-directory, so it's only "." that is behaving strangely.

Comment: That's not my experience. `git diff HEAD` from anywhere does a diff of the whole repo, but `git diff HEAD .` limits the output to things contained in the current directory.

Comment: OK. Got it. I had GIT_DIR setup, so it always compared the CWD to GIT_DIR.